# In C++: How to overwrite an element to an array by moving entries below it up by one

Tags: c++, arrays, overwrite

I am trying to "delete" an element in my array. I have been told by those who know C++ better than I do that to accomplish this I must move all entries below the one I want to delete up by 1. Afterwards, I must decrease by 1 the variable keeping track of the size of the array. So I wrote this code to accomplish that:

```
cout << "Type the number of the inventory entry you would like to delete:\n";
        cin >> entryToDelete;

        for ( count = 0 ; count < (entryToDelete - 1) ; count++)
                list[count] = list[count + 1];

position--;
```

I previously displayed for the user the entries in the array as #1, #2, #3, etc while their subscripts are 0, 1, 2, etc... That is why I put `entryToDelete - 1`. `position` is the variable that keeps track of the size of the array. Anyway, I use this code to output the array so I can check if the code worked:

```
for (int count = 0 ; count <= position ; count++)
        {
                cout << "Entry #" << (count + 1) << endl;
                cout << "ISBN: " << list[count].ISBN << endl
                     << "Author: " << list[count].Author << endl
                     << "Title: " << list[count].Title << endl
                     << "Quantity: " << list[count].Quantity << endl
                     << "Price: " << list[count].Price << endl << endl;
        }
```

For some reason, no matter what number I input to delete, the last element in the array is deleted. I have tried several modifications, such as changing the order of the array elements to modify: i.e. `list[count + 1] = list[count]`, but this does not give me what I want.

Unfortunately, I am restricted from using vectors.

Comment: You misheard them. They told you to move elements *above* the one being deleted *down* by 1. So the element at `entryToDelete+1` is copied into `entryToDelete`th slot, element at `entryToDelete+2` is copied into `entryToDelete+1`st slot, and so on.

Comment: below/up, above/down, right/left - all just different ways to visualise the array... it's less ambiguous - and in keeping with the Standard Library containers - to do what Oswald's done and refer to the front (i.e. where element `[0]` is) vs. back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. It moves all the elements into place and removes the entry you wanted to delete.

```
  for ( size_t count = entryToDelete; count < arraySize - 1 ; ++count)
    list[count] = list[count + 1];

  --arraySize;
```

Comment: This was the most useful to me out of all the responses. However, it did not work perfectly. This is the code that finally made it happen: `for ( count = (entryToDelete - 1) ; count < position ; count++)
                list[count] = list[count + 1];

        position--;`

Comment: Ah right fair enough, I assumed entryToDelete started from 0 but arraySize (or num of elements) started from 1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move all elements to the right of that element one to the left.

[image]

[Here](https://ideone.com/rS7Dn0) is a simple code that shows how to move elements to the left

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[10]=  {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int numToDelete = 5;

    for (int i = numToDelete; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++ )
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    }

    arr[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) - 1] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the entries following the deleted element to the front by one.